# Panda: how to assign colors to specific values on a pie chart?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to assign a color to each discrete value in order to plot different pie charts by keeping the same color for each value.

Let's say we have to pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1
       val
20.0    14
30.0    22
40.0    12
50.0    15
60.0    2
80.0    2
90.0    3
220.0   1
230.0   1
```

and

```
df2
       val  
20.0    31
30.0    19
40.0    31
50.0    30
80.0    1
90.0    1
110.0   6
160.0   14
220.0   57
230.0   1


f,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,5))
df1.plot.pie(y='val', ax=ax[0])
df2.plot.pie(y='val', ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

I would like to map the colors from a dictionary like the following

```
color_mapping1 = {0: "black", 20:'#FFBB22', 30:"#FFFF4C", 40:"#F096FF", 50:"#FA0000", 60:"#B4B4B4",
                 70:"#F0F0F0", 80:"#0032C8", 90:"#0096A0", 100:"#FAE6A0", 110:'#58481F', 
                 120:"#009900", 130:"#70663E", 140:"#00CC00", 150:"#4E751F", 160:"#007800", 
                 170:"#666000", 180:"#8DB400", 190:"#8D7400", 200:"#A0DC00", 210:"#929900",
                 220:"#648C00", 230:"#000080"}
```

Comment: Does this help? [Change color of pie chart according to section label (pandas/matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106189/change-color-of-pie-chart-according-to-section-label-pandas-matplotlib)

Comment: @a11 yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.